# Folder on root, not under Inbox generates error: The attempted operation failed. An Object Could not be found

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

I have created a folder on root, not under Inbox. What is the syntax to move to root folder?

I'm getting error:

> The attempted operation failed
>
> An Object Could not be found

Debug points to the below line `myRestrictItems(i).Move myFolder.folders("Business")`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()

    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myRestrictItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItem As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim Msg As String


    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myFolder.Items

    Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                   Chr(34) & " >= '01/01/2018' And " & _
                   Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                   Chr(34) & " < '23/03/2018' And " & _
                   Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname" & _
                   Chr(34) & "Like '%Jayakumar Krishnamoorthy%'"


    Set myRestrictItems = myItems.Restrict(Filter)

    For i = myRestrictItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        myRestrictItems(i).Move myFolder.folders("Business")

    'Msg = myRestrictItems.Count & " Items in " & myFolder.Name & " Folder"

    'MsgBox (Msg)

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have subfolder name `Business` under inbox?

Comment: I have created folder on root, not under Inbox. Now Created and Tested with 0m3r suggessions, it worked great. What is the syntax to move to root folder "Business"

Comment: Can you post an image of your outlook folders?

Comment: Sorry, I could not share the screenshot of the mailbox, as it is my office mailbox.

Comment: yes, the folder "Business" is in the same level as Inbox.

Comment: Set myFolder = myNamespace.folders("your email address").folders("Business")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The correct syntax should be*

---

> ```
> myRestrictItems(i).Move myNamespace.Folders("Business")
> ```

---

*Also Move you `msgbox` outside the loop, Example*

```
Set myRestrictItems = myItems.Restrict(Filter)

Msg = myRestrictItems.Count & " Items in " & myFolder.Name & " Folder, Move it?"

If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    For i = myRestrictItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        myRestrictItems(i).Move myNamespace.Folders("Business")
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Thanks 0m3r, Modified as you suggested, the script works like a Champ, I have created a folder under my Inbox and it works fine and successfully moved. What is the syntax if I have to move it to root folder "Business"

Comment: @Jayakumarkrishnamoorthy answer updated with correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

Run a quick loop through the folders to `debug.print` their names and any other properties you might find useful. The displayed name and internal name may not be the same.